# Bounding the condition number by the eigenvalues

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $M$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix. It is about bounding the condition number, $cond (M) = \|M\| \|M^{-1}\|,$ by it's eigenvalues given some matrix norm $\|\ \|$ and assuming $\|Mx\| = \|M\| \|x\|, x\in \mathbb{R}^n.$ I want to show, $cond(M)\geq |\frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}}|,$ for $\lambda_{max},\lambda_{min}$ the largest and smallest eigenvalue of $M.$ In case of the spectral norm I can get an equality by using the spectral radius. I do not see why there would rather hold in general an inequality. Can one provide some suggestion or a solution proposal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ and $v\ne0$ is a corresponding eigenvector, then you have that
$$
\|M\| = \sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|Mx\|}{\|x\|} \ge \frac{\|M v\|}{\|v\|} = \frac{|\lambda| \|v\|}{\|v\|} = |\lambda|
$$

Since the eigenvalues of $M^{-1}$ are the inverses of the eigenvalues of $M$, you know that, for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M$, $\|M^{-1}\| \ge \frac{1}{|\lambda|}$.

Finally,

$$
cond(M) = \|M\| \|M^{-1}\| \ge |\lambda_{\max}| \cdot \frac{1}{|\lambda_{\min}|}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption on the Matrix $M$ makes this identity in fact kind of trivial. Defining $\tilde{M} = \frac{1}{\lVert M \rVert} M$ we see that $\tilde{M}$ is isometric and bijective, i.e. orthogonal. Thus its eigenvalues are located on the unit circle. Since the eigenvalues of $M$ correspond to the eigenvalues of $\tilde{M}$ multiplied by $\lVert M \rVert$, one observes that $\left\lvert \frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min} } \right\rvert$=1. But it also holds
$$ 1 = \lVert \tilde{M}^{-1} \rVert = \lVert M \rVert \lVert M^{-1} \rVert. $$
Hence, both sides are equal to one.

Comment: Dividing a matrix by a its norm does not make the matrix generally orthogonal nor does it move its eigenvalues on the unit circle. Just consider a diagonal matrix with distinct diagonal entries.

Comment: Of course it does not. But the OP's assumption on the Matrix $M$ was $\lVert Mx \rVert = \lVert M \rVert \lVert x \rVert$ in which case this does indeed hold.

Comment: I see, I missed that. Though it seems to me that it’s a typo in the question.